# Is there a way to copy portions of an array buffer to another one?

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

I have a array buffer containing vertices and I want to remove sections of it at a time.

I've tried using glBufferSubData to fill the sections I want to remove with zeroes but when I add new vertices it just adds them to the buffer after the zeroes.

So I wanted to try copying the portions of the buffer around the part I want to remove.

Comment: [`glCopyNamedBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyBufferSubData.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`glCopyBufferSubData`/`glCopyNamedBufferSubData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glCopyBufferSubData.html) to copy data from the data store of one buffer object to the data store of another buffer object.
When using `glCopyBufferSubData`, you must bind the buffer objects to the specified read and write target. When using the DSA (Direct Status Access) version (`glCopyNamedBufferSubData`) the buffer object must be specified directly..